# Combine multiple items from observable to new objects using RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I'm trying to implement some kind of streaming parser. Let's say that I have stream of integers, and I combine them to create new object, which aggregates part of stream.

For example, object is "done" when integer is negative. To keep it simple, produced items will be strings of numbers.

Here is simple example:

```
Source: 1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, 9, 10, -11
Output: "1-2", "343-5", "6-7", "8910-11"
```

I can't find proper combination of existing operators. My solution was to provide custom operator, which aggregates data till "chunk" is valid and emits new object:

```
rx.Observable<Integer> src = rx.Observable
    .from(Arrays.asList(1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, 9, 10, -11));

rx.Observable<String> res = src
    .lift(new rx.Observable.Operator<String, Integer> () {

        @Override
        public rx.Subscriber<? super Integer> call(
            final rx.Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

            return new rx.Subscriber<Integer>(subscriber) {

                private final StringBuilder cur = new StringBuilder();

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                        subscriber.onError(e);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer i) {
                    if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed())
                        return;

                    cur.append(i).append('');
                    if (i < 0) {
                        subscriber.onNext(cur.toString());
                        cur.delete(0, cur.length());
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });

rx.observers.TestSubscriber<String> sub =
    new rx.observers.TestSubscriber<>();
res.subscribe(sub);
List<String> l1 = sub.getOnNextEvents();
```

It works well till I use some positional operators on them, like *take(N)* or *combineLatest*.

```
rx.Observable<String> res2 = res.take(2);
```

In this situation I don't get *onCompleted* or *onError* and smaller amount of items are emitted.

It looks like each input *onNext* should have output *onNext* called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Writing long post did help to come with new idea and it works. (I bang head the wall 2 days already).

Produce `Observer<Observer<String>>` and emit `Observer.empty()` till object is ready. `flatMap` after.

Here is working example:

```
rx.Observable<rx.Observable<String>> res = src
    .lift(new rx.Observable.Operator<rx.Observable<String>, Integer> () {

        @Override
        public rx.Subscriber<? super Integer> call(
            final rx.Subscriber<? super rx.Observable<String>> subscriber) {

            return new rx.Subscriber<Integer>(subscriber) {

                private final StringBuilder cur = new StringBuilder();

                // onError, onCompleted skipped

                @Override
                public void onNext(Integer i) {
                    rx.Observable<String> out;
                    cur.append(i);
                    if (i < 0) {
                        out = rx.Observable.just(cur.toString());
                        cur.delete(0, cur.length());
                    } else {
                        out = rx.Observable.<String>empty();
                    }
                    subscriber.onNext(out);
                }
            };
        }
    });

rx.Observable<String> res2 = res
    .flatMap(stringObservable -> stringObservable)
    .take(2);
```